# How to save Form as PDF with python

Tags: python, pdf, flask, flask-wtforms

What is the bet way to make formatted document from form in python flask.

I have python Flasks service that allows user to update database items within browser using Flask WTForm. I need to find way to make PDF (or some other format) documents out of Form. Is there good tool for this.

I have try [pdfkit](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/) but it seams difficult to install and I would need to have it run in Google cloud or AWS but I just don't know how.

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using xhtml2pdf?
Assuming you already have a template ready, you can basically create a python script as follows :-

```
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from cStringIO import StringIO

def create_pdf(pdf_data):
    pdf = StringIO()
    pisa.CreatePDF(StringIO(pdf_data.encode('utf-8')), pdf)
    return pdf
```

Also here's the link I had referred from :- http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/68/

This has documentation links to xhtml2pdf :)